# Visual Studio 2017 OleDB Xamarin.Forms

Tags: banco-de-dados, mobile, xamarin-forms, microsoft-access, visual-studio-2017

Galera estou precisando de ajuda no seguinte, estou fazendo um projeto multiplataforma usando Visual Studio 2017 e Xamarin.Forms, o problema é: preciso fazer uma conexão com Banco de Dados Access da MS.

Eu já vi diversos tutoriais e todos usavam a `OleDB` para fazer a conexão, no entanto no meu projeto não consigo adicionar a `System.Data.OleDB` como referencia pois ela simplesmente não não aparece para adicionar, alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Comment: Onde estaria hospedado esse banco de dados? na nuvem ou local?

Comment: O banco de dados fica hospedado na nuvem